# Assigning access rights to roles in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Most articles/examples I'm finding regarding access rights for asp.net mvc are related to restricting access to specific controllers using roles but I'm trying to figure out how can specific access rights be assigned to a user that belongs to a specific role.

My scenario is rather simple as the only role that requires access rights at the user level is the "Staff Members" role:

- Admin: Access to all features.
- Staff: Access to specific features.
- Member: No access to specific features.

Ideally, I'd like to implement something similar to the below

```
@if (@User.IsInRole("IsAdmin") || (@User.IsInRole("IsStaff") && 
     @User.HasAccess("DownloadData"))
{
    <a href='@Url.Action("DownloadData"....
    </a>    
}
```

I've got a separate table where I store the staff access rights and since these are assigned at the user level, I'm using the same `Id` generated in `AspNetUsers` so a simple EF/SQL Linq join does the trick when I log in to get the relevant access rights for a specific staff member.

Now my questions are:

1. Can I expand the @User (Principal) to have a scenario similar to the above by introducing a new function such has `HasAccess` where I could pass the Access Right that needs to be checked for the specific staff member.
2. If 1. can't be done, would passing the logged-in user access right to the ViewModel used to build my page be a viable option? Is it too risky? Am I wrong to assume that this should be ok since this is server based code and wouldn't be passed along to the client side?
3. If 1 & 2 are not suitable, what is the best/recommended method to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create an extension method on `IPrincipal` or `IClaimsPrincipal`. This way you can unify the access rights definitions in a single place. If you have lots of access rights checks, maybe you need to add the access rights as claims (if you're using claims) or cache them somehow so you don't need a database access everytime (if they are stored on the database).

Also, you're right that it is the same if you pass the access right to the view, because the view is rendered to HTML. But, IMHO, the first option is much better as you don't need to clutter your Controller with Access Rights checks.

Comment: Ok, I'll go research option 1 and see what can be done. If you have any links of interests, would you mind posting them.

Comment: I found this question on SO and while it explains well how to extend the IPrincipal, I'm still not sure how to use it. Do I replace my ApplicationUser : IdentityUser by ApplicationUser : UserPrincipal where UserPrincipal inherits from IPrincipal?

Comment: In newer versions of ASP.NET MVC you don't need to extend the Principal as it uses claims. You just add your access rights as new claims. Also, to add the function to check for the access rights, maybe it's enough to create an extension method, instead of using inheritance.

Comment: assuming I add claims and create an extension, does that extension need to query the claims table based on the UserIdentity.Id? Sorry, but I'm confused. I understand I could add claims as a user is created by the administrator, but how do I update these these? Delete and re-create on update? Seems messy.

Comment: When you log in the user, you need to add the access rights a claims (querying the database) to your ClaimsPrincipal. Then, on the extension method, you can query those claims directly from the principal's identity.

Comment: Excellent! I'll continue this tonight and let you know how I got on.